# El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos

Tags: python, django

Necesito ayuda con este error que me aparece al ejecutar el comando "python manage.py runserver" en la consola del visual studio code, estoy trabanjando en un proyecto de Django, trato de entrar a la pagina principal o index.html del proyecto:

Exception in thread django-main-thread:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Django\diagramacodigo\diagramacodigo\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', include('core/urls')),
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core/urls'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 599, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 584, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 299, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 305, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 345, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 361, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 260, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 141, in iter_modules_and_files
    resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\pathlib.py", line 1123, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\pathlib.py", line 184, in resolve
    return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
```

OSError: [WinError 123] El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos: ''

el error aparecio tras configurar los archivos de settings.py y views.py

esto es lo que tengo en mi diagramacodigo/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core/urls')),
]
```

esto es lo que tengo en mi core/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import home

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name="home"),
]
```

esto es lo que tengo en mi core/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(request):
    return render (request, '/core/home.html')
```

esto es lo que tengo en mi diagramacodigo/settings.py: aqui solo agregue el 'core' al final del arreglo:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
]
```

asi tengo organizadas la carpetas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes mostrar las views y settings profa, puedes editar la publicación, y si tienes algo en el modelo también.

Comment: path('', include('core/urls')), ese es tu problema, si tenes alguna url igual coloca el archivo de urls para mirar

Comment: ahi agregue mas detalles

Answer (score 2):

El error está en:

```
path('', include('core/urls')),
```

Cambia la barra `/` por un punto `.`:

```
path('', include('core.urls')),
```